# How to get Mercurial to ignore Vim's .swp file?

Tags: vim, mercurial, hgignore

I tried to pull some changes while I had some files opened in vim, and while committing and merging and the sort, ended up coming up with:

```
alex@adebian:~/cs4290/p3$ hg status
R test
! project3_framework/protocols/.MI_protocol.cpp.swp
! project3_framework/protocols/.MSI_protocol.cpp.swp
```

I added a `.hgignore` file in my project with the following:

```
syntax: glob
*.cpp.swp
```

I've since closed my vim session (removing the files) yet the files keep showing up.  How do I get mercurail to ignore the .swp files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`!` sign means that mercurial cannot find the file that has been already added to the repository. So you need to `forget` or `remove` those files at first. After that - they will not appear anymore in the `status` since you have ignored them.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with zerkms... `forget` or `remove` those files to get rid of the `!`. Also, as you've probably noticed, simply creating a .hgignore file with some content does not go through the repository and remove matching files. If you've added `foo.c` to your project and then you create the following .hgignore:

```
syntax: glob
*.c
```

`foo.c` will still be a part of the project - you would need to remove it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 
`set directory=c:\\workfiles\\` 
in your .vimrc to write swap files in a "special" folder

Comment: This is a useful workaround.  The only downside is if you have two files from different folders with the same name.

Comment: Just tried it out on my linux box, got a file named index.php.swp
index.php.swo. Seems to work, at least for me.